# Sysdate in text sql

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, sysdate

I´ve got a problem, I want to have the sysdate in a text, 
currently my Where-statement looks like this:

```
where optxt_text like '%Mahnstufe 2 29.06.2016%' 
  and (reverse(rpad(reverse(optxt_belnr),3))) in ('KAG','KRE','KSR') ;
```

Is there a way to replace the "29.06.2016" with the sysdate?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: yes, it's possible, but you need to tell us what DB you're using. in mysql it'd be `like concat('%..., cur_date(), '%')`

Comment: I´m using an oracle DB, but this isn´t working for me :-/

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
where optxt_text like '%Mahnstufe 2 '+CONVERT(nchar, getdate(), 104)+'%'
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the trim:

    SELECT '%Mahnstufe 2 '+ltrim(rtrim(CONVERT(nchar, getdate(), 104)))+'%'

without trim, the date is followed by spaces or Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

Solution was:

```
LIKE '%... '||to_char(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY')||'%'
```